# Java 7 nio list directory with wildcard

Tags: java, nio

I'd like to find a file in a directory using wildcard. I have this in Java 6 but want to convert the code to Java 7 NIO:

```
 File dir = new File(mydir); 
 FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(identifier+".*");
 File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

There is no `WildcardFileFilter`, and I've played around a bit with globs.

Comment: Have you read [Finding Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443793/allow-wildcards-to-search-for-subdirectories-from-a-parent-directory. It should help you in constructing right code for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass a glob to a DirectoryStream

```
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
...

Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( filePath );
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream( dir, "*.{txt,doc,pdf,ppt}" );
for (Path path : stream) {
    System.out.println( path.getFileName() );
}
stream.close();
```

Comment: I think you need a cast no? for (Path path : (Path) stream) {

Comment: @Jabda, you're right. This is now fixed (DIrectoryStream<Path> ... added).

Answer (score 7):

You could use a [directory stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) with a [glob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String%29) like:

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, identifier+".*")
```

and then iterate the file paths:

```
for (Path entry: stream) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was specifically for Java 7, but it also comes up as the first result for this question in general. With Java 8 and higher the way to do this wit NIO is to use `Files.find` with a `BiPredicate<T, U>`.

```
Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(
        Paths.get("/dirToSearch"),
        1, // Search depth of 1 in our case, set to >1 or -1 to explore subfolders
        (path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
            String filename = path.getFileName().toString();
            return filename.startsWith("identifier");
        }
);
// The stream is lazily populated
Path firstMatch = stream.findFirst().get();
```