# Is there really not a way to do a wildcard file search using Java File?

Tags: java, file

It looks like these are the ways to get a list of files from Java
(from here: [Using File.listFiles with FileNameExtensionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter))

**Option 1:**

```
File dir = new File("/users/blah/dirname");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

**Java 8 Option:**

```
pdfTestDir.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"));
```

**Question:**

Is there really not a way to use a typical file wildcard expression like "./foo/**/admin/*.txt"? Something like:

```
File dir = new File("/users/foo/bar");
dir.listFiles("./foo/**/admin/*.txt");
```

or maybe something like

```
SomeUtil.listFiles(file, "./foo/**/admin/*.txt");
```

**Similar to:**

This question is similar to this Stackoverflow post, however this post doesn't really address the question of the recursive case (e.g. "./../*.txt").

[How to use a Wildcard in Java filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993946/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-java-filepath)

Also similar to this [How to find files that match a wildcard string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java) (which looks more promising, but also does not ask/answer the question why isn't this part of the Java core implementation).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39995413/133203 for inspiration

Comment: Of course there's a way. `listFiles()` just isn't it.

Comment: `dir.listFiles("./foo/**/admin/*.txt");` should cause a compiler error because there is no verwion of `listFiles()` that takes a `String` argument. I suggest checking [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html). There is an option that takes `FileFilter` that might be helpful.

Comment: java.io.File is part of Java 1.0, which means it was released in 1995.  Use the more modern [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class instead.

Comment: The solution I ended up using is documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993946/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-java-filepath/63565111#63565111