# How to find and retrieve full filename with changeable date suffix

Tags: java, regex, file, datetime, file-io

I have a file that is being generated every time. The name of the file changes every time and consists of a fixed prefix,
followed by suffix of the current date.
I need a way to find the filename using maybe regex or something else, using only the known prefix like:

```
 String localFile = "my_path" + "PREFIX_*";
 File localFile = new File(localFileStr);
 if (localFile.exists()) {
     return localFile;
 }
```

Example of the filename:

```
the prefix: PREFIX_
pattern1: yyyy-mm-dd
pattern2: _hh-mm-ss 
all together: PREFIX_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss 
Actual example: PREFIX_2022-11-27_10-45-14
```

As you can see, it consists of the prefix, date of year, month and day separated by _ then hour, minutes and seconds.
I need something to add, maybe separate for 2 dates patterns and a way to use regex on searching through the given directory.

Comment: You can use [File.listFiles(FileFilter)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) to find files in a directory whose names match certain criteria.

Comment: Seems related: [Java 7 nio list directory with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088245/java-7-nio-list-directory-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.time` API to parse the filename into a `LocalDateTime` and then compare the date part with today's date. If the parsing fails or the criterion for the current date is not met, you can return `false` from [`FileFilter#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html#accept-java.io.File-).

**Demo of parsing and the criterion for the current date**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'PREFIX_'uuuu-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String fileName = "PREFIX_2022-11-27_10-45-14";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(fileName, parser);
        System.out.println(ldt);
        System.out.println(ldt.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now()));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-27T10:45:14
true
```

Now, let's create a `FileFilter` using the above-explained concept:

```
FileFilter todaysFilesFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        String fileName = file.getName();
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'PREFIX_'uuuu-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            if (!LocalDateTime.parse(fileName, parser).toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now()))
                return false;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

The final step is to get the list of files,

```
File[] files = your-directory.listFiles(todaysFilesFilter);
```

---

<sup>Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.</sup>

Comment: very good use of `FileFilter`

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash Thanks for the answer, helped me a lot. Can I send dynamic prefix to make it generic? As a variable to be sent to accept method through the abstract class? Same question for date format (if sometimes it's month before year or opposite)

Comment: @elads11 - Most welcome. You can create a function as shown [here](https://ideone.com/S8Gi2O) and then `FileFilter todaysFilesFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return isAcceptable(file.getName());
    }
};`. Wish you success!